# Gitlab backup to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have started backing up my Gitlab data to AWS S3 bucket as per instruction(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html). As of now it is working fine but I'm unable to move this data automatically to sub folder in S3 bucket(like s3://my_gitlab_bucket_backup/`NewFolder`)

Currently, I performed following changes to move the backup to root folder in bucket.

```
gitlab_rails['manage_backup_path'] = true
 gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/backups"
 gitlab_rails['backup_archive_permissions'] = 0644 # See: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#backup-archive-permissions
 gitlab_rails['backup_pg_schema'] = 'public'
 gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800
 gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
   'provider' => 'AWS',
   'region' => 'us-east-1',
   'aws_access_key_id' => 'ABCDEF',
   'aws_secret_access_key' => 'XYZAL'
 }
 gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'my_gitlab_bucket_backup'
```

Any help to move this backup to sub-folder in bucket will be highly appreciated

Comment: This is confusing, have you started the backup? and you just want to move already backed up files to the sub folder?

Comment: what changes i have to perform in gitlab.rb files so that next time onward my backup files will auto move to sub folder in S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

Given that the configuration above works, and **my_gitlab_bucket_backup** has the backups deposited into the root folder of your bucket. If you want to place subsequent backups into **your_folder** (a path/folder at the root of your bucket), you can try to use a new feature by setting `DIRECTORY=` on your [backup rake task](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) as noted [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23221).

e.g. `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create DIRECTORY=your_folder`

If you are asking for a feature that will move the older backup files into this folder, I do not believe that exists.

Comment: was looking for this myself, and the only reason I found it was your posts @Rahul Sahotay